# Limit of $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0^+} e^{\frac{x}{x}}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, derivatives

If I need to find $$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0^+} e^{\frac{x}{x}}$$ I know that since $e$ is a constant I can take it out and make the equation $$e^{\lim_{x \rightarrow 0^+} {\frac{x}{x}}}$$ Then use L'Hopital's Rule and differentiate $\frac{(x)'}{(x)'}=1$ and get that $e^{\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+}1}=e^1$. Is my approach correct?

Comment: L'Hospital should be nearer to a last resort than a first resort.

Comment: It should be obvious that the function here is constant and equal to $e$ if $x\neq 0$ and hence the desired limit is $1$. There is no need to invoke any tools like L'Hospital's Rule.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh  
But if it were a different equation where you had to convert from the normal form to $e$ form would my method still work?

Comment: What do you mean by normal form to $e$ form? Can you explain with some example?

Comment: For example, find the limit of $f(x)=x^{1/x}, x=0$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note simply because: $$\frac{x} {x} =1$$ we have: $$\lim_{x \to 0^+} e^{\frac{x} {x}} = \lim_{x \to 0^+} e^1 = e$$

Comment: But if it were a different equation where you had to convert from the normal form to $e$ form would my method still work?

Answer (score 0):

note that $$\frac{x}{x}=1$$ if $x\neq 0$ so the searched limit is $e^{1}=e$